# How to print variable/debug data from your extension.php?

Tags: extension, developer, gsoc, debugging

I am trying to add a menu entry in the navigation, but this is causing the navigation menu to disappear, I am trying to debug the code but could not find any particular file.

I have checked the following:

- Browser's Javascript Console
- CiviCRM logs from ConfigAndLog folder
- Apache2 log

Is there anything else I should check? Is there any way I can print the data in the `extension_civicrm_navigationMenu(&$params)` function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(**Update**) As of v4.7.0, the approaches below still work, but there's a better way to write to the log file using a [PSR-3](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-3-logger-interface.md) logger, e.g.:

```
Civi::log()->info('Hello, log!');
Civi::log()->error('I'm sorry, {name}. I'm afraid I can't do that.', array(
  'name' => 'Stanley Kubrick',
));
```

See also:
https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/the-static-is-dead-long-live-the-static

---

To write out to CiviCRM's `ConfigAndLog` folder, one can use either:

```
CRM_Core_Error::debug_log_message('hello log');
CRM_Core_Error::debug_var('name', $var);
```

There's also an experimental [PSR-3](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-3-logger-interface.md) logger (`CRM_Utils_SystemLogger`) which writes out to the database (table `civicrm_system_log`), e.g.

```
$log = new CRM_Utils_SystemLogger();
$log->info("hello log");
$log->error("I'm sorry, {name}. I'm afraid I can't do that.", array(
  'name' => 'Stanley Kubrick',
));
```

If the debug statement is temporary (won't be committed/redistributed), then you can usually use CMS-specific functions (like Drupal devel's `dpm()` or Joomla's `JLog`).